# Редирект с одной jsp на другую. Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-data

Структура проекта следующая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все jsp находятся в директории WEB-INF и поэтому просто так к ним не постучаться.

**Внимание вопрос!**

Имеется header.jsp страница,которая генерирует вот такую вот шапку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Войти" и "Регистрация" ссылки и в зависимости от условий

```
<a href="bla-bla" class="navbar-link" name="LogIn" style=" color: #f0ffff;">
  <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${not pageContext.session['new']}">
       <c:choose>
          <c:when test="${user != null}">
            <c:out value="Welcome,${user.getName()}"/>
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
          <c:out value="Войти"/>
          </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
          <c:out value="Войти"/>
    </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-link" style="color: #f0ffff;">
    <c:choose>
      <c:when test="${not pageContext.session['new']}">
         <c:choose>
           <c:when test="${user != null}">
              <c:out value="Выйти"/>
           </c:when>
           <c:otherwise>
              <c:out value="Регистрация"/>
           </c:otherwise>
         </c:choose>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
         <c:out value="Регистрация"/>
      </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</a>
```

отображают тот или иной текст.
Как правильно реализовать редирект на ту или иную jsp, находящихся в директории WEB-INF, при этом задавать адрес в атрибуте href ?

Например с кнопкой type="submit" такого вопроса нет,т.к. в контроллере из request достаю название и делаю redirect на другую jsp и все хорошо,работает, но в данной ситуации необходима именно ссылка. Может быть возможно ее тоже можно каким-то образом обработать в контроллере, если да, то каким образом? Если возможно решить данную проблему иным способом буду рад выслушать предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Решение оказалось на поверхности) Пример со страницей авторизации href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login". В контроллере мапим login и происходит долгожданный redirect.

Comment: блин... Вы же Spring MVC вроде используете? Так и используйте его, почитайте про MVC, про DispatcherServlet, про мапинг и аннотации... и не кладите логику приложения в представление.